# Google Search Appliance Feed Error

Tags: java, character-encoding, google-search-appliance

According to the following document, i've parsed and constructed xml files that contains meta tags for feeding.

https://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/feedsguide/feedsguide.html#1073742

Altough the send post (http request via specific port) returns Success, i see the error below so the feeding was failed:

> Skipping the rest of the feed, Line number: 1, Error: Couldn't find
>   end of Start Tag meta

I thought that this is because the special chars in the xml file i send to feeding. Do you have any ideas and so any solution about it?

Here is the XML sample i send for feeding:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<gsafeed>
    <header>
        <datasource></datasource>
        <feedtype>metadata-and-url</feedtype>
    </header>
    <group>
        <record url="url.xml" action="add" mimetype="text/html" lock="true">
            <metadata>
                <meta name="city" content="sample" />
                <meta name="cityName" content="sample" />
                <meta name="town" content="sample" />
                <meta name="type" content="sample" />
                <meta name="area" content="sample" />
                <meta name="price" content="sample" />
                <meta name="currency-code" content="USD" />
                <meta name="description" content="" />
                <meta name="heading" content="_" />
            </metadata>
        </record>
    </group>
</gsafeed>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<meta name="description" content="" />
```

Empty content on meta tag is not allowed.

Comment: Do Html tags like <p>, <ul> etc. allowed in a meta content? İf not, what can i do for that tags?